# Capitalising minor words in titles

Tags: capitalization

I once learnt that we do not capitalise minor words in titles (articles, conjunctions (a bit ambiguous), and prepositions (a bit ambiguous, too)). However, I later came up with a question: don't we even capitalise those words when they are kind of the topic of discussion?

Examples (let's imagine those are titles):

1. **The Article *the***

1.2. **The Article *The***

2. **How to Use *a* Correctly**

2.2. **How to Use *A* Correctly**

3. **Guidance on Using *by* and *with* in the Passive Voice**

3.2. **Guidance on Using *By* and *With* in the Passive Voice**

Comment: It's probably just a matter of opinion: style guides don't go into this detail. Although in math and metrology you probably want to keep lower case. Note that depending on the topic *i* and *I* might be entirely different things.

Comment: Just noting that this must be an American-English question. In British English, we wouldn't capitalise anything but the first word, and would probably put the italics in quotes to make the mention clearer.

Comment: When “the” is not being used as an article, the rule would not apply anyway. One way around the problem would be to capitalise the entire title.

Comment: Suit yourself (or your editor); nobody will sue you for miscapitalization. The safest thing to do is copy it directly off the title page or the copyright page -- that's the way the author and publisher wanted it, after all.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion and cannot be answered here. My daughter, a UX designer, only capitalises the first word unless proper nouns are in play. I capitalise major words and I've seen every word capitalised by others. There are other factors, such as your company's style manual, if it exists.